# Updating values in django

Tags: python, django

- I am trying to update the profile value of a particular user. If the user has logged in for the first he needs to go to `Edit Profile` and then enter the details which are getting stored in the database.
- When I am trying to update the values of a `User Profile`. It is not getting updated in the database.
- I know the code is not that perfect but I am just trying to do it through normal logic. You can also find the comment in the code which represent what the code of block is doing.
- Code

```
# edit user profile
def edit_profile(request):
    try:
        # checking if the user exist in UserProfile through the logged in email id
        user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        name = UserProfile.objects.all()
        response_data = {}
        # when the submit button is pressed
        if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
            name = request.user.username
            emailID = request.user.email
            phone = request.POST.get('phone')
            college_name = request.POST.get('college_name')
            branch = request.POST.get('branch')

            response_data['name'] = name
            response_data['emailID'] = emailID
            response_data['phone'] = phone
            response_data['college_name'] = college_name
            response_data['branch'] = branch
            try:
                # checking if the user exist
                # if the user exist update the values
                user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
                if(user_data.emailID == request.user.email):
                    UserProfile.objects.filter(emailID = request.user.email).update(
                        name = name,
                        emailID = emailID,
                        phone = phone,
                        college_name = college_name,
                        branch = branch
                    )
                    return render(request, 'user_profile.html')
            except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                # if the user doesn't exist create the user
                UserProfile.objects.create(
                    name = name,
                    emailID = emailID,
                    phone = phone,
                    college_name = college_name,
                    branch = branch
                )
            return render(request, 'user_profile.html')
    else:
        # if the profile is already created fetch the values
        context = {
            'name' : user_data.name,
            'emailID' : user_data.emailID,
            'phone' : user_data.phone,
            'college_name' : user_data.college_name,
            'branch' : user_data.branch
            }
        return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {'context' : context})
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html')
```

Comment: Your `if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':` is inside the `except` block. So , if the profile exists, the `if` code will not be executed. Is the indentation correct in your question?

Comment: Solved I have updated the solution in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Solution. The issue was just of me placing the update method below. So I just brought the update method above the except condition.

```
# edit user profile
def edit_profile(request):
    try:
        # checking if the user exist in UserProfile through the logged in email id
        user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
        if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
            name = UserProfile.objects.all()
            response_data = {}
            name = request.user.username
            emailID = request.user.email
            phone = request.POST.get('phone')
            college_name = request.POST.get('college_name')
            branch = request.POST.get('branch')

            response_data['name'] = name
            response_data['emailID'] = emailID
            response_data['phone'] = phone
            response_data['college_name'] = college_name
            response_data['branch'] = branch
            # updating the current logged in user values
            user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
            if(user_data.emailID == request.user.email):
                UserProfile.objects.filter(emailID = request.user.email).update(
                    name = name,
                    emailID = emailID,
                    phone = phone,
                    college_name = college_name,
                    branch = branch
                )
            return render(request, 'user_profile.html')
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        name = UserProfile.objects.all()
        response_data = {}
        # creating new user
        if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
            name = request.user.username
            emailID = request.user.email
            phone = request.POST.get('phone')
            college_name = request.POST.get('college_name')
            branch = request.POST.get('branch')

            response_data['name'] = name
            response_data['emailID'] = emailID
            response_data['phone'] = phone
            response_data['college_name'] = college_name
            response_data['branch'] = branch
            try:
                # checking if the user exist
                user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
            except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                # if the user doesn't exist create the user
                UserProfile.objects.create(
                    name = name,
                    emailID = emailID,
                    phone = phone,
                    college_name = college_name,
                    branch = branch
                )
            return render(request, 'user_profile.html')
    else:
        # if the profile is already created fetch the values
        context = {
            'name' : user_data.name,
            'emailID' : user_data.emailID,
            'phone' : user_data.phone,
            'college_name' : user_data.college_name,
            'branch' : user_data.branch
            }
        return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {'context' : context})
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html')
```